# web meeting at LAN speed?

Tags: conferencing

I would like to have a web meeting solution at LAN speed.

I need to show my clients how fast my apps are via web conferencing. I hope to put the app server and the meeting server on the same LAN segment.
WebEX and Citrix do not really serve the purpose. They have to transverse over what WAN bandwidth is available and go to their server. In the case, my application does not appear to run as quickly

Comment: www.join.me is pretty awesome. i use for about 10-15 people while demoing web applications.

Comment: it is not in LAN